# How to give duplicate name in the url bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to duplicate the names in the url bar. For example i am having `products controller` and `index method`. Now in my project i am running like `localhost:89733/Products/Index`. But instead of `Products/Index` what want to give another name to run the same `action method`. How can i do that. I mean i don't want to leak my controllers information to others. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure a custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductsRoute",
    "mycustomproductsname/{id}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now when you navigate to `mycustomproductsname/123`, the `Index` action of the `Products` controller will be executed and passed 123 as `id` parameter.

Comment: suppose if we have 10 controllers and 10 index pages then we need to add 10 map routes. And for each action method i need to add another map route. And what is "ProductRoute" in that

Comment: `"ProductRoute"` is the name of the route. Each route should have an unique name. As far as the duplication is concerned, you could have some pattern in which the controller name should somehow be part of the route. For example: `"mycustom{controller}sname/{id}"`. This way the controller name could be passed in the url. As you can see the `Index` is no longer part of the url but is inferred. But if you don't want to have any indication about any controller name in the url you will have to do separate route mappings. If you are asking me the whole purpose of this is completely meaningless...

Comment: But i have implemented what u say in the register routes function. I have run that with new url name but is is not working

Comment: Did you remove the default route? Also define *not working*? What url did you type in the address bar? How does your `MapRoute` looks like precisely?

Comment: yah after removing default route it is working. But we should initially give the default route so that initially a page will be called

Comment: The default route should be placed **after** your custom routes because it is less specific. Routes are evaluated by the routing engine in the same order you defined them. So always put more specific routes to the top.

Comment: Still we have lot many controllers and lot many actions. so we need to define so many routes is it so or any other process.

Answer (score 0):

*i Hope Routing can solve the purpose  In Global.asax file  apllication start event*

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


}   


public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //Treeview routing
    routes.MapPageRoute("Home", "User/Dashboard", "~/Products/Index");
    routes.MapPageRoute("SearchCustomer", "User/Search-Customer", "~/Products/SearchCustomer");



}
```

i Hope you were asking for this and it helps you

Comment: In the above example "~/Products/Index" refers to User/DashBoard isn't it